# JpaRepository and CrudRepository error

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

Why happen such error?
I am using Spring Data JPA 1.3.3 , Spring 4.2.8 and Spring MVC 4.2.8.

[image]

UPDATE:
Error as code block

> Error:Error:line (8)java: name clash: save(java.lang.Iterable) in org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository and save(java.lang.Iterable) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

All my libraries added as IntelliJ Idea's Module. Only JSTL is downloaded by Maven.

[image]

Comment: Please add errors as code blocks not images as they become unreadable.

Comment: It's probably due to dependencies conflict. Check your dependencies versions or add it to question.

Comment: Also get rid off the @Query, you don't need it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added errors as code block

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar If keep my interface empty you get the same result

Comment: Can you add your gradle/maven file and your User class in the question.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar I add screen

Comment: Upgrade your spring version to 4.3.5.RELEASE and JPA to 1.10.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have dependency problem. An older version of Spring Data Common with Spring Data JPA might be the problem.

Comment: I use Spring Data JPA 1.3.3 and Spring Data Commons Core 1.1.0. This is the reason the error?

Answer (score 0):

For spring data jpa, It's not really good idea to write native query in repo. Unless your demands are just to hard to write query methods.

For your case, you just need simple query methods like this

```
List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);
```

Return list of User because many Users might have the same userName

Take a look at spring data doc [Query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

Hope it help :)

Comment: Ohh ok!! But your problem was because of spring being confuse native & methods query. you may want to clarify which one to use by rename your method or add `nativeQuery = true`  to your native query param

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the Ignite Spring Data and Spring JPA dependency issue - you need to downgrade `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa` version to 1.11.23.RELEASE. Thanks to @chirdeep-tomar [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431556/jparepository-and-crudrepository-error#comment70088076_41431556)!

In my project compatibility issues of `IgniteRepository` and `CrudRepository` with `deleteAll()` method were solved with the following Maven configuration:

```
    'org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.3.RELEASE'
    'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.23.RELEASE'
    'org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data:2.9.0'
    'org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:2.9.0'
    'org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:2.9.0'
```